# CallByName with 2 functions

Tags: scala

I have the next code, where I study call by name.

```
def callByName(v1: => Int) ={
  println(v1)
  println(v1)
}

val fn1 : (Int => Int) = {println("calling fn1 "); _ + 100}

callByName(fn1(1))

println("=================")

val fn2 = (x: Int) => {println("calling fn2 "); x + 100 }

callByName(fn2(1))
```

I expect the same output, but it is:

```
calling fn1
fn1: Int => Int = <function>89c5c0

101
101

=================

fn2: Int => Int = <function>d15e781

calling fn2
101
calling fn2
101
```

I know that the second case is a "function literal (also known as an anonymous function)".

Could you tell me please where I can read about these 2 cases or explain? Thanks.

And the third case:

```
val fn1 : (Int => Int) = {println("calling fn1 "); _ + 100}

println(fn1(1))
println(fn1(2))
println(fn1(3))
```

Output:

```
calling fn1
fn1: Int => Int = <function>da62626

101
102
103
```

In this last case "body of the function executed 3 times", but only last part "_ + 100" and the first part only 1 time "println("calling fn1 ");"

Huh.

Comment: i would suggest you to read about curry functions. fn1 is a function which takes Int as input and return Int, fn2 is a curry function which return a function which takes exactly one input which is of type int that's why in the second case you are getting the body of the function each time in the output.

Comment: Forget about by-name arguments and what not for a second, and just execute the line `val x: Int = { println("computing x"); 42 }` in isolation. What does it print? What's the difference between `x` and `fn1`? Does `42` print anything on the STDOUT if you use it repeatedly?

Comment: @RamanMishra I don't know what you wanted to tell us. Both `fn1` and `fn2` are of same type, namely `(Int => Int)`. What's the point of reiterating it?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin as far as I know, please correct me if I am wrong that I’m the one case the function we are getting in return is already evaluated which is fn1 and in fn2 we are getting the whole function which is getting evaluated each time.

Answer (score 1):

Well... So your first case is bit weird and causing some confusion to you.

So, your first case,

```
val fn1 : (Int => Int) = {
  println("calling fn1 ")
  _ + 100
}
```

is actually,

```
val fn1 : (Int => Int) = {
  println("calling fn1 ")
  val xx: Int => Int = _ + 100
  xx
}
```

It is similar to,

```
val i: Int = {
  println("creating int")
  5
}
```

So, your `fn1` is just that `xx`. It has no relation with `println("calling fn1 ")` line.

Where as in your second case `println("calling fn2 ")` is also part of `fn2`.